# Facing problem during Conference upgradation

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, atlassian-sourcetree, confluence, sonatype

I am a newbie in this arena. Due to project demand, I had to install the newest version of Confluence. So, I have taken the backup and install confluence 6.12 on top of 6.6. After completing the installation when I hit the URL I have got the following error message.

[image]

Comment: i have added this "-Dconfluence.upgrade.recovery.file.enabled=false" but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

- Roll back the instance by restoring the backup you made prior to attempting the upgrade. Do this by creating a fresh Confluence install (I would recommend using the same version of Confluence that you used to create your XML backup). Restore the XML backup to this.
- Get that site working normally first.
- Then connect to a supported database.
- Proceed with the upgrade.